# Xine on Intel: how to enable VDPAU or VAAPI?

Tags: intel

On my dell laptop
vga is

```
Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics
```

I have downloaded and installed on slackware 14.1
libvdpau-gl,vdpau-intel-driver,and of course libva.
Mplayer works fine,xine is ultraslow,give me this error

```
"vdp_status_no_implementation"
```

and video is fast like a 3d game with 3d disabled.
I see vaapi option is missing on xine,why?

I tried to add manually vaapi on xine/config
give me this error

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.34.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib64/va/drivers/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_34
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vo_vdpau: vdpau API version : 1
vo_vdpau: vdpau implementation description : OpenGL/VAAPI/libswscale backend for VDPAU
vo_vdpau: maximum video surface size for chroma type 4:2:2 is 1920x1080
vo_vdpau: maximum video surface size for chroma type 4:2:0 is 1920x1080
vo_vdpau: maximum output surface size is 8192x8192
vo_vdpau: Failed to check vdpau get/put bits native capability : VDP_STATUS_NO_IMPLEMENTATION
```

I try to recompile but won't compile vaapi,i have installed latest vaapi now

Comment: What's the value of `video.driver` in `~/.xine/config`? Is it set to `vaapi`?

Comment: vaapi is missing,i try to set manually

Comment: What version of Xine do you have?

Comment: Latest xine lib 1.2.6

Comment: What about the other packages involved? In particular, `__vaDriverInit_0_34` indicates you're not running the latest `libva`...

Comment: Try installing `libva-intel-driver` as well.

Comment: Installed: /var/log/packages/libva-intel-driver-1.2.1-x86_64-1alien

Comment: Ouch that's old (although Haswell is supported in 1.2.1). The missing `Xv` functions you're seeing in your build are in `libXv`, presumably you need to install the Slackware equivalent of `libxv-dev` or add `-lXv` to the build.

Comment: Thanks compile fine.But won't compile vaapi,i don't understand why,i have installed vaapi lib and driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,i had to navigate into Xine settings and use
vdpau or auto.